# Why $\bar{z_1}z_2+\bar{z_2}z_3+\bar{z_3}z_1 \in \mathbb R \iff z_1, z_2, z_3 \text{ are along the same line}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove:

$$\bar{z_1}z_2+\bar{z_2}z_3+\bar{z_3}z_1 \in \mathbb R \iff z_1, z_2, z_3  \text{ are along the same line}$$

My attempt:

Since $z+\bar{z} =2  \operatorname{Re}z \in \mathbb R$, so we can transform like that:
$$\bar{z_1}z_2+\bar{z_3}z_2+\bar{z_3}z_1 + \bar{z_1}z_1 \in \mathbb R$$
next
$$(\bar{z_1}+\bar{z_3})(z_1+z_2) \in \mathbb R$$
But we should have something like
$$\frac{z_1+z_3}{z_1+z_2} \in \mathbb R$$

So, what is missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are almost done! Note that $\frac{z_1+z_3}{z_1+z_2}\in\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to $\frac{z_1+z_3}{z_1+z_2}=\frac{\bar{z_1}+\bar{z_3}}{\bar{z_1}+\bar{z_2}}$.

Comment: You're not using $z+\bar{z}\in\mathbb{R}$, but rather that $z\bar{z}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Take a look at another  solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3070084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply your last fraction top and bottom by $\overline{z}_1+\overline{z}_2$