# Prove three distinct complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ lie on a straight line iff $\bar{z_1}z_2+\bar{z_2}z_3+\bar{z_3}z_1=r$ which $r$ is a real number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> A.
>   Prove three distinct complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ lie on a straight line iff 
>    $\bar{z_1}z_2+\bar{z_2}z_3+\bar{z_3}z_1=r$ which $r$ is a real number.
>   B.
>    Prove three distinct complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ lie on a straight line iff there are non-zero $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ such that $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=0$ and $\lambda_1z_1+\lambda_2z_2+\lambda_3z_3=0$

I already knew one condition is $z_1-z_2=r(z_2-z_3)$ for some real number . But don't know how to infer these two conditions. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: You could start deriving B. from the assertion you already know?

Comment: I just found that I could prove B.

Comment: Be careful that your problem requires checking both necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921220

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution that is different from the solution given in  [Why $\bar{z_1}z_2+\bar{z_2}z_3+\bar{z_3}z_1 \in \mathbb R \iff z_1, z_2, z_3 \text{ are along the same line}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/921220) :

Do you know that the equation of the straight line passing through $z_1$ and $z_2$ is

$$\begin{vmatrix}z_1&z_2&z\\ \overline{z_1} &  \overline{z_2}& \overline{z}\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0 \ ?$$

(see for example [Equation of line in form of determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2111593))

Thus $z=z_3$ belongs to this line iff it verifies the above equation, giving the following condition :

$$\begin{vmatrix}z_1&z_2&z_3\\ \overline{z_1} &  \overline{z_2}& \overline{z_3}\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0\tag{1}$$

which, once developed, is equivalent to

$$\overline{z_2}z_1+\overline{z_1}z_3+\overline{z_3}z_2=\overline{z_1}z_2+\overline{z_3}z_1+\overline{z_2}z_3 \tag{2}$$

But the LHS of (2) is the conjugate of its RHS. Thus this is possible iff this RHS is real, finding the given condition.